# Java CipherInputStream NegativeArrayIndexException on close()

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I have a problem with a simple decrypt implementation using CipherInputStream and a standard 128 bit AES Cipher.  The code is below (*The instance variable `buf` is just a simple 1024 length byte array used as a buffer*):

```
public void decrypt(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
    CipherInputStream cin = null;
    try {
        // Bytes read from in will be decrypted
        cin = new CipherInputStream(in, dcipher);
        // Read in the decrypted bytes and write the result to out
        int numRead = 0;
        while ((numRead = cin.read(buf)) >= 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, numRead);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Exception in decryption of inputstream!", e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (cin != null) cin.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            log.error("Exception in closing CipherInputStream!", ioe);
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that the server that performed the encryption and stored the result in a database is always able to successfully decrypt the data and stream.  If a different server retrieves the encrypted data however and attempts to decrypt it, it appears to work successfully until it attempts to close the CipherInputStream.  The following exception occurs on `cin.close()`.

```
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.close(DashoA13*..)
    at com.company.util.Encryptor.decrypt(Encryptor.java:104)
    ...
```

It is interesting this is happening in doFinal, it would make me think that it is not done doing *something* before it is being closed.  I am not sure what it means though.  I am also wondering if the fact that it always works on the encrypting server just a coincidence (*this is repeatable on different workstations*)?

Any insight would be helpful.

**EDIT:** I am adding code for the creation of the Cipher objects.  Nothing special really, but I wonder if this has to do with being a static class and a Singleton in the context of a stateless web application?  At the very least I imagine this is pointless as this Singleton utility class will need to be reinstantiated on every request anyway...

```
String key = PropertyManager.getInstance().getProperty("phikey");
    try {
        ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        byte[] raw = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(key);
        SecretKey skey = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey);
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        log.error("No encryption algorithm present!", e);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        log.error("No such padding for encryption!", e);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        log.error("Invalid key exception!", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Unable to decode encryption key!", e);
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

I suddenly can't get this to occur anymore on my development machines and I didn't change anything!  I have come to the conclusion that we can't find a solution to this with the information we know.  I am taking the helpful suggestions of people below and putting a hot fix to the production servers that will do some extremely detailed logging so when this happens again, we will know more about what is happening behind the scenes.  Thanks for your help so far and I will leave this open in case anybody else experienced the same problem.

Comment: Are you sure that instances of `Cipher` on both servers were created with the same transformation names, especially with the same padding specifications?

Comment: @axtavt I added more code and description above... it should be using the same key and padding I would think?

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure but maybe the key has incorrect length. Replace `SecretKeySpec` with `PBEKeySpec` as the former does not check for correctness of the key.

Comment: @MisterSmith I appreciate the advice however this app is already in production and this problem never cropped up until after we added an additional production server.  Wouldn't moving to a PBE cipher key require us to decrypt and reencrypt ALL of our encrypted production data?  If so then that would be an **OMFG'DISASTER** for me and my team.

Comment: Yup, you are right. Just a question, is the key constant? I mean, the same for both apps in different servers?

Comment: @MisterSmith Yes they are exactly the same, unless Base64Decoder works differently between machines?  I even compared the keys in a hex editor just to make absolutely sure there were no rogue characters hiding somewhere.

Comment: Does it decrypt the data correctly before calling `close()`?

Comment: That would be a good test: to compare the `raw` array in each server and also the `skey.getEncoded` and `skey.getFormat` output.

Comment: You say that the ciphers are held in a static singleton class. Are the ciphers used in a multithreaded environment?

Comment: @Qwerky Yes they could be... like I said this is a web application and while the instance of my Encryptor singleton is static, I would have thought that being request/response based that each request spawns a new instance of the JVM thus a unique static pool.  I suppose it would be safe to synchronize these methods just in case.  Thanks for the suggestion!